# how can create a plot with square size?

Tags: r, plot

I have used below script for drawing a plot but it gave me rectangular plot, I would like to draw a square plot. I have used 'width=4, height=4' but it did not work.

```
data:
             A1     A2     A3 
  s1        0.5     0.3    0.6
  s2        0.6     0.2    0.1

matplot(cbind(data$A1,data$A2,data$A3), type = c('p'),pch=c(19,19),col = 1:3,las=1,xaxt='n')
```

Comment: try `matplot(cbind(data$A1,data$A2,data$A3), type = c('p'),pch=c(19,19),col = 1:3,las=1,xaxt='n', asp=1)` ... depending on the plot, the `asp=1` typically forces an aspect ratio of 1

Comment: It didn`t work, I want X-axis and Y-axis with the same size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `?par`

> ```
> pty
>      A character specifying the type of plot region to be used; "s"
>      generates a square plotting region and "m" generates the maximal
>      plotting region.
> ```

In your case, try

```
windows(width = 8, height = 8)
par(pty = "s")
matplot(cbind(data$A1,data$A2,data$A3), type = c('p'),pch=c(19,19),col = 1:3,las=1,xaxt='n')
```

Comment: @ thanks d.b. it is working but is there any way for bigger square plot

Comment: I can work with your script. but I would like to know, is there any way for bigger square?